# Testing Alexa Skills with audio playback - is this expected behavior?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am making an audio skill using the audio player template with the source code from the [official Amazon repo](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/tree/mainline/multiple-streams).

Additionally, I have also followed suit with the instructions and added the required `PlayAudio` intent with the required utterances.

I am using EchoSim to test my Skill. This is the JSON from `SpeechSynthesizer.Speak`:

```
{
 "directive": {
  "header": {
   "dialogRequestId": "dialogRequestId-d2e37caa-98b6-4aec-99b1-d24298e422d5", 
   "namespace": "SpeechSynthesizer", 
   "name": "Speak", 
   "messageId": "43150bc3-5fe1-44f0-aeea-fbec4808a4ce"
  }, 
  "payload": {
   "url": "cid:GlobalDomain_ActionableAbandon_52324515-eee3-4232-b9e4-19edeab556c5_1919623608", 
   "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.#ACRI#GlobalDomain_ActionableAbandon_52324515-eee3-4232-b9e4-19edeab556c5", 
   "format": "AUDIO_MPEG"
  }
 }
}
```

My problem is: this links to a `mp3` audio, **but no audio is playing**. I was wondering if this is indeed the correct response I should be getting, and that its working this way simply because I am not testing on a device, or if there is anything I should modify?

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: mp3 file needs to be in 48 kbps format.. refer to this link https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#h3_converting_mp3   , if its in correct format.. capture logs from cloudwatch and update in your question

Answer (score 1):

The common issues with audioplayer interfaces is the strict audio requirements, this looks the reason of your issue. The link provided by Amod is for the SSML not audioplayer. Make sure to follow all the requirements for audio stream:

- Audio file must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint on
  port 443.
- The web server must present a valid and trusted SSL certificate.
  Self-signed certificates are not allowed (really important).Many
  content hosting services provide this. For example, you could host
  your files at a service such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon
  S3) (an Amazon Web Services offering).
- If the stream is a playlist container that references additional
  streams, each stream within the playlist must also be hosted at an
  Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint on 443 with a valid and trusted
  SSL certificate.
- The supported formats for the audio file include AAC/MP4, MP3, PLS,
  M3U/M3U8, and HLS. Bitrates: 16kbps to 384 kbps.

This information  an be found on the official documentation below:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements

Comment: Edited, requirements for SSML and audio player are sightly different, and this is one common issue.